# Runing multiple instances with the same, single ip address

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-vpc

Using Amazon VPC, what is the best possible way to attach multiple instances to a single ip address?

My company needs the ability to open/shutdown instances upon request and traffic. All instances created must have the same ip address attached, as the service I try to connect to allows only certain IPs that I can define every once in a while.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to whitelist the IPs of your instances to some other third party service, then you would have to use elastic IPs in that case. You can not associate one IP to more than one instance.

However, if you want only one endpoint for your service, you can very well use load balancer as also suggested above.

Comment: Thank you for your response
Let's say I have an ELB defined on my VPC (2 identical instances in the same AZ) means I'll redirect all traffic to the ELB hostname and the ELB acts like a traffic cop and send the requests to any of instances in my VPC.

Now, These VPC instances needs to transmit data somewhere else that has an ip whitelist, incase I have associated the instances with an EIP, that means the ELB will recieve the request and the instances within will send it out ? under what IP addresses ?

My goal is to have the ability to send requests from my instances under the same IP

Comment: After your ELB sends traffic to your instances, if the logic on your instance needs to contact some other service, it will contact directly. In case of outgoing traffic from your instances, your ELB wont be coming in the picture.

At the third party service end, the IP of your instance will be shown in the incoming traffic. Hence, you would need to whitelist all the EIPs of your instances to the third party.

I hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks again. How does the ELB handles TCP and UDP protocols ?
If data needs to be sent back to one of the servers under the ELB can the ELB direct the incoming data to right instance ?

Comment: Yes, you would need to configure Listeners for directing traffic to your instances.

In AWS console, select your ELB and go to Listeners tab and configure corresponding listener.

Answer (score 3):

You want to use Elastic Load Balancer (ELB). It was built specifically for the purpose of balancing a large number of requests to the same IP across several EC2 instances.

http://aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/

Comment: Hii @0x90 and thanks for your reply.
Can I attach an EIP ro ELB ?
Dosen't ELB takes care of inbound traffic ? My issue here is outbound traffic.

Comment: If the answer was useful to you please upvote and/or accept the answer :)

Comment: Can I attach an EIP ro ELB ? Dosen't ELB takes care of inbound traffic ? My issue here is outbound traffic.